# C:Pointer Arithmetic -How does it work?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm new to C programming and trying to understand how pointer arithmetic works. The below printf statement prints 2 when the arguments for printf is *(p+2) and 4 with for *p. Could you please explain this behaviour ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = {4,3,2,1}, *p = arr;
    printf("\n%d", *(p+2));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Go through some tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's re-write your program to make it a little clearer:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[4] = {4,3,2,1};
    int *p = arr;
    printf("\n%d", *(p+2));
    return 0;
}
```

Now, `*(p+2)` is by definition the same as `p[2]`. Since `p` points to the first element of `arr`, then `p[2]` is the same as `arr[2]` which is equal to `2`.

Similarly, `*(p)` is the same as `*p` and since `p` points to the first element of `arr` then `*(p)` is `4`.

You probably need to re-read the section in your text book that covers pointer arithmetic.